# Implicit argument in constructor vs method signature

Tags: scala, type-inference, generic-programming, implicits

What difference does the compiler see in `BroFinder1` and `BroFinder2` that causes the first one to fail? I really need `BroFinder1` to work as it is without utilizing patterns such as Aux Pattern.

```scala
trait Brother[I] {
  type Bro
  def get: Bro
}

class Foo
object Foo {
  implicit object bro extends Brother[Foo] {
    override type Bro = Bar

    override def get = new Bar
  }
}

class Bar {
  def barSpecificAction(): Unit = ()
}

class BroFinder1[I](implicit val b: Brother[I]) {
  def brotherOf: b.Bro = b.get
}

class BroFinder2[I] {
  def brotherOf(implicit b: Brother[I]): b.Bro = b.get
}


new BroFinder1[Foo].brotherOf.barSpecificAction() // Doesn't compile
//error: Error:(73, 32) value barSpecificAction is not a member of _1.b.Bro
//new BroFinder1[Foo].brotherOf.barSpecificAction();
                          ^
new BroFinder2[Foo].brotherOf.barSpecificAction() // Ok

//scala version: 2.12.4
```

Comment: Error message please.

Comment: @RichDougherty updated the post.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a perfect answer but probably will provide some insights. The issue seems to be not related to `implicit` at all. It seems to be related to another fairly advance Scala feature: ***path-dependent types***. Particularly the trouble seems to come from the fact that Scala type system is not powerful enough to express type difference between `finder1` and `finder2` precisely in following code:

```
object Foo {

  implicit object bro extends Brother[Foo] {
    override type Bro = Bar

    override def get = new Bar
  }

  object bro2 extends Brother[Foo] {
    override type Bro = Foo

    override def get = new Foo
  }

}


val finder1 = new BroFinder1[Foo]
val finder2 = new BroFinder1[Foo]()(Foo.bro2)
val bof1 = finder1.brotherOf
val bof2 = finder2.brotherOf
```

***Sidenote***: the fact that some parameter is `implicit` doesn't make it a "constant" because you can always pass the parameter explicitly anyway or you can have different visible implicit values in different contexts.

AFAIU the most precis type the `finder1` or `finder2` might be assigned in this example is just `BroFinder1[Foo]`. Particularly there is no way to catch different values of the `b` implicit variable and thus there is no way to pass further exactly the value of the path-dependent type that is encoded inside that value. Thus the best compiler knows about the types of `bof1` and `bof2` is that they both have type in form of `_1.b.Bro` where `_1` means some particular instance of `BroFinder1[Foo]`. And so the compiler can't be sure that `bof1` is actually of type `Bar` while `bof2` is of type `Foo`.

The second example works because implicit parameter is captured in the same context so compiler knows exactly what the result type of `brotherOf` is.

The only workaround I know is not exactly suitable in your case: use "***Aux***" type. If your `BroFinder` took also an explicit parameter of type `Foo`, the solution might have looked like this:

```
type BrotherAux[I, B] = Brother[I] {type Bro = B}

class BroFinder3[I, B](val v: I)(implicit val b: BrotherAux[I, B]) {
  def brotherOf: B = b.get
}

new BroFinder3(new Foo).brotherOf.barSpecificAction()
```

But in your case it has to be much less helpful

```
class BroFinder1[I, B](implicit val b: BrotherAux[I, B]) {
  def brotherOf: B = b.get
}

new BroFinder1[Foo, Bar].brotherOf.barSpecificAction()
```

Comment: gosh I was really hoping Aux wasn't the solution. too many type parameters aside from making code ugly, also in my case caused some implicit resolution issues that only after introducing type members in code were solved. maybe I should have asked that question

Comment: @shayan, usually making the question as close to the real thing as possible is a good idea. You can wait a while for other answers and then if there is no better ones, ask a new question with a closer example (and probably reference this one to get more meaningful answers).

Comment: @shayan, still I wonder why you really want a fully-independent "brother" type instead of just implicit wrapper class such as `RichInt` or `StringOps`

Comment: do you mean ```implicit class ExtensionMethods[T](t: T) {def brotherOf[B](implicit b: Brother[T]): b.Bro = b.get}``` ? sry I wasn't sure what u meant.

Comment: @shayan, no I meant getting rid of `brotherOf` altogether and moving all `barSpecificAction` methods to something like `implicit class FooBrotherMethods(val foo:Foo) extends AnyVal`. One of such methods may also return a companion object similarly to what Scala's standard collections `companion` method does. In other words, I don't get your real problem and what you shown looks like an example of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I see. I'm writing library code the needs to be generic and relies on occasion on type classes such as above to automatically provide behavior for possible concrete implementations. none of the code you see above exists in reality I spent hours trying to pin down the current problem in my code and write a short dumbed down ```Foo``` ```Bar``` example. Which I now suspect hasn't been to my benefit at all :P

Comment: @shayan, this sound quite suspicious to me. IMHO typical type class in Scala is a generic trait that lists all methods, and implicit `val`s and/or `def`s that let you create instance(s) of that trait specific to the given type. And all you do in your type-class-aware code is use methods from that trait. So how come that `barSpecificAction` is not defined in such trait but you still want to call it from "outside"?

Comment: Keen observation. it's really complicated to explain in text but this only occurs in 1 place in my code. I'm considering creating a question for it. the AST itself if omitting those ugly generated implicits for tuples (like the one you see in ```slick tuple shapes```) is about 100 lines of code + some lines of client code that reproduce the issue. would that be a good idea to post the entire thing on stackoverflow and ask what's wrong with it?

Comment: @shayan, 100 lines doesn't sound as too much. But what I believe is much more important is not just show your code to solve the problem - describe the actual problem you are trying to solve so that SO users might suggests higher-level solutions.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to take a look at [my new question on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47707034/implicit-resolution-of-fbounded-type) when you had time?

Answer (score 3):

Because `new BroFinder2[Foo].brotherOf` is of type `Bar` and `Bar` has method `barSpecificAction` but `new BroFinder1[Foo].brotherOf` is of existential type

```
x.Bro forSome { val x: Brother[Foo] }
```

and it doesn't have method `barSpecificAction`.

Comment: with drop of existential types in dotty does this mean a change to how it'll be compiled is it is?

Comment: In dotty 0.6.0-bin-20171207-63e491a-NIGHTLY in console
`scala> val bar1 = new BroFinder1[Foo].brotherOf` produces
`val bar1: Main.BroFinder1[Main.Foo]#b.Bro = Main$Bar@4657d37a`
although `val bar1: BroFinder1[Foo]#b.Bro  = new BroFinder1[Foo].brotherOf` doesn't compile. So existential types exist but you can't use them. Surely `val bf = new BroFinder1[Foo];
val bar1: bf.b.Bro = bf.brotherOf` compiles both in Dotty and Scala.