# compiler failure to resolve Implicit types with bounds (sometimes)

Tags: scala, type-inference, implicit, functional-dependencies, play-json

**Edit**:

Last revision was deemed unhelpful as it did not contain necessary information that help narrow down my issue. hence the need to also include the AST.

Below is a library in its entirety that allows parsing and writing of `play-json`'s json based on user defined schema; Similar to what Scala's `slick` offers for database columns to some extent:

```scala
import scala.language.higherKinds
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json._

import scala.language.{higherKinds, implicitConversions}

type PathNodes = List[PathNode]

sealed trait Field[A] {

  def pathNodes: PathNodes

  def jsPath: JsPath = JsPath(pathNodes)

  def relativePath: JsPath = JsPath(List(pathNodes.last))

  def format: Format[A]

  def nestedFormatter(path: JsPath): OFormat[A]

  def nestedFormat: OFormat[A] = nestedFormatter(relativePath)
}

case class PlainField[A: Format](prefix: PathNodes) extends Field[A] {

  override def pathNodes: PathNodes = prefix

  def format: Format[A] = implicitly[Format[A]]

  override def nestedFormatter(path: JsPath): OFormat[A] = path.format(format)
}

abstract class JsonSchema[T](val _prefix: PathNodes) extends Field[T] with SchemaExtensionMethods {

  override def pathNodes: PathNodes = _prefix

  def format: OFormat[T]

  protected def plain[A: Format](name: String): PlainField[A] = PlainField[A](_prefix :+ KeyPathNode(name))

  protected def nested[N](name: String, factory: PathNodes => N): N = factory(_prefix :+ KeyPathNode(name))

  protected def nested[B, G <: JsonSchema[B]](name: String)(implicit sm: HasJsonSchema[B, G]): G = sm.apply(_prefix :+ KeyPathNode(name))

  override def nestedFormatter(path: JsPath): OFormat[T] = path.format(format)
}

case class Optional[F, A](field: F)(implicit ev: F <:< Field[A]) extends Field[Option[A]] {

  override def pathNodes: PathNodes = field.pathNodes

  override def format: Format[Option[A]] = {
    implicit val writes: Writes[Option[A]] = JsPath.writeNullable(field.format)
    implicit val reads: Reads[Option[A]] = JsPath.readNullable(field.format)
    implicitly[Format[Option[A]]]
  }

  def map[G, B](f: F => G)(implicit ev: G <:< Field[B]): Optional[G, B] = new Optional[G, B](f(field))

  def flatMap[G <: Field[B], B](f: F => Optional[G, B]): Optional[G, B] = f(field)

  override def nestedFormatter(path: JsPath): OFormat[Option[A]] = path.formatNullable(field.format)
}

case class Collection[F, A](field: F)(implicit ev: F <:< Field[A], repath: Repath[F]) extends Field[Seq[A]] {
  override def pathNodes: PathNodes = field.pathNodes

  override def format: Format[Seq[A]] = {
    implicit val writes: Writes[Seq[A]] = Writes.seq(field.format)
    implicit val reads: Reads[Seq[A]] = Reads.seq(field.format)
    implicitly[Format[Seq[A]]]
  }

  def apply(idx: Int): F = implicitly[Repath[F]].apply(field, IdxPathNode(idx))

  override def nestedFormatter(path: JsPath): OFormat[Seq[A]] = path.format(format)
}

class FormatExtensionMethods[T](val arg: T) {
  def <>[A, B, Fun](apply: Fun, unapply: B => Option[A])(implicit jss: JsonShape[A, B, T, Fun]): OFormat[B] = jss.format(arg, apply, unapply andThen (_.get))
}

class FieldExtensionMethods[F](val field: F) {
  def optional[A](implicit ev: F <:< Field[A]): Optional[F, A] = new Optional[F, A](field)

  def sequence[A](implicit ev: F <:< Field[A], repath: Repath[F]): Collection[F, A] = new Collection[F, A](field)
}

trait SchemaExtensionMethods {
  implicit def formatExtensionMethods[M](t: M): FormatExtensionMethods[M] = new FormatExtensionMethods[M](t)

  implicit def fieldExtensionMethods[M, A](t: M): FieldExtensionMethods[M] = new FieldExtensionMethods[M](t)
}

trait Repath[F] {
  def apply(f: F, node: PathNode): F
}

object Repath {
  implicit def plain[T]: Repath[PlainField[T]] = new Repath[PlainField[T]] {
    override def apply(t: PlainField[T], node: PathNode): PlainField[T] =
      PlainField[T](t.pathNodes :+ node)(t.format)
  }

  implicit def schema[S <: JsonSchema[_]](implicit sm: HasJsonSchema[_, S]): Repath[S] = new Repath[S] {
    override def apply(t: S, node: PathNode): S =
      sm.apply(t.pathNodes :+ node)
  }

  implicit def option[F <: Field[T] : Repath, T]: Repath[Optional[F, T]] = new Repath[Optional[F, T]] {
    override def apply(t: Optional[F, T], node: PathNode): Optional[F, T] =
      new Optional[F, T](implicitly[Repath[F]].apply(t.field, node))
  }

  implicit def sequence[F <: Field[T] : Repath, T]: Repath[Collection[F, T]] = new Repath[Collection[F, T]] {
    override def apply(t: Collection[F, T], node: PathNode): Collection[F, T] =
      new Collection[F, T](implicitly[Repath[F]].apply(t.field, node))
  }
}

trait JsonShape[A, B, -T, Func] {
  def format(t: T, apply: Func, unapply: B => A): OFormat[B]
}

object JsonShape {
  type F[T] = Field[T]

  implicit def cc1[A, B]: JsonShape[A, B, F[A], (A) => B] = (t: F[A], apply: (A) => B, unapply: B => A) => {
    val name = t.pathNodes.last.asInstanceOf[KeyPathNode].key
    OFormat[B](
      Reads[B](jsv => (jsv \ name).validate[A](t.format).map(apply)),
      OWrites[B](b => JsObject(Map(name -> Json.toJson(unapply(b))(t.format))))
    )
  }

  implicit def cc2[T1, T2, B]: JsonShape[(T1, T2), B, (F[T1], F[T2]), (T1, T2) => B] = (t: (F[T1], F[T2]), apply: (T1, T2) => B, unapply: B => (T1, T2)) => {
    (
      t._1.nestedFormat and
        t._2.nestedFormat
      ) (apply, unapply)
  }

  implicit def cc3[T1, T2, T3, B]: JsonShape[(T1, T2, T3), B, (F[T1], F[T2], F[T3]), (T1, T2, T3) => B] = (t: (F[T1], F[T2], F[T3]), apply: (T1, T2, T3) => B, unapply: B => (T1, T2, T3)) => {
    (
      t._1.nestedFormat and
        t._2.nestedFormat and
        t._3.nestedFormat
      ) (apply, unapply)
  }

  //this goes up to 22

}

abstract class HasJsonSchema[T, +S <: JsonSchema[T]](val apply: PathNodes => S) extends OFormat[T] {
  val root: S = apply(Nil)

  def format: OFormat[T] = root.format

  def writes(o: T): JsObject = root.format.writes(o)

  def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[T] = root.format.reads(json)
}
```

Now let's write a small piece of client code that reproduce the issue:

```scala
case class MessageSchema(prefix: PathNodes) extends JsonSchema[Message](prefix) {

  def underlying = plain[String]("underlying")
  //def underlying = plain[String]("underlying").optional if I wanted the field to be Option[String]
  //def underlying = plain[String]("underlying").sequence if I wanted the field to be Seq[String]
  override def format = underlying <> (Message.apply _, Message.unapply)

}

case class Message(underlying: String)

object Message {

  implicit object sm extends HasJsonSchema[Message, MessageSchema](MessageSchema.apply)

}

case class LanguageTaggedSchema[T, S <: JsonSchema[T]](prefix: PathNodes)(implicit evT: HasJsonSchema[T, S]) extends JsonSchema[LanguageTagged[T]](prefix) {
  def lang = plain[String]("lang")

  def data: S = nested("data")(evT)

  def format = (lang, data) <> (LanguageTagged.apply[T] _, LanguageTagged.unapply[T])
}

case class LanguageTagged[T](lang: String, data: T)

object LanguageTagged {

  implicit def schemaMapper[T, S <: JsonSchema[T]](implicit ev: HasJsonSchema[T, S]): HasJsonSchema[LanguageTagged[T], LanguageTaggedSchema[T, S]] =
    new HasJsonSchema[LanguageTagged[T], LanguageTaggedSchema[T, S]](LanguageTaggedSchema.apply[T, S]) {}
}

def toJson[T, S <: JsonSchema[T]](a: T)(implicit ev: HasJsonSchema[T, S]): JsValue = Json.toJson(a)(ev.format)

toJson(Message("hi")) //Ok!
toJson(LanguageTagged("en", Message("hi"))) //Ok!
//or simply write
Json.toJson(LanguageTagged("en", Message("hi")))

//and if i wanted to traverse a json path i would do:
val schema = implicitly[HasJsonSchema[LanguageTagged[Message],LanguageTaggedSchema[Message,MessageSchema]]].root
schema.data.underlying.jsPath
//prints: res2: play.api.libs.json.JsPath = /data/underlying

//Now to where the problem starts:

def getSchema[T, S <: JsonSchema[T]](a: T)(implicit ev: HasJsonSchema[T, S]): S = ev.root

getSchema(Message("hi")) //Ok!
getSchema(LanguageTagged("en", Message("hi"))) //Not Ok but why?
//Error:(211, 11) could not find implicit value for
//parameter ev: A$A6.this.HasJsonSchema[A$A6.this.LanguageTagged[A$A6.this.Message],S]
//getSchema(LanguageTagged("en", Message("hi")));//
//^
```

I have a huge suspicion that the compiler runs into issues because of the bounded type of `S` in`HasJsonSchema[T, S <: JsonSchema[T]]` when infering the implicit type S. and so far only in that specific situation as shown on the last line of all the code. as a dubugging attempt I created a similar situation and realized that if the type `S` was not bounded I wouldn't have this issue. Any sort of solution that refactors the code such that it doesn't depend on bounded types or one that simply solves the implicit resolution is appreciated

Comment: Could you provide some more details on what `repath` does and why it has to return `S` instead of just `JsonSchema[T]`?

Comment: @SergGr I updated the post with your required information

Comment: Sorry, your are showing some code to show some problem but you avoid describing what the actual problem is. This severely limits possible answers and also make the question much harder (because to answer you have to read the code). Also your examples seems to be absolutely not related as things such as `root` or `reaplies` or `postedBy` are not mentioned anywhere before and thus it is hard to guess what they really are. So once again, could you, please, describe the problem you are trying to solve in terms of logic rather than code?

Comment: @SergGr I truly appreciate how much you've been trying to help me so far. I revised the question and put everything I could in to help narrow down the issue. if you need to run it. just copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

What You're trying to achieve cannot be done with subtyping. You should use type-classes instead, a more in-depth explanation:

http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html